# gdb backtrace does not display virtual function it is coming from

Tags: c++, gdb

I have a `Derived` class that inherits from `Base` and I have a crash in one of my function. I opened up gdb to try and figure out what was going on and tried to print out a backtrace. however it only showed that it had called `Base::func` when I know 100% that the path is: `Derived::func` -calls> `Base::func` but it doesn't show the `Dreived::func` part in the backtrace. Is there some setting that I am missing that I can't seem to find in the manual?

Comment: Please show the class declarations for the relevant portions of the base class and the derived class, and a the trace you are seeing.

Comment: I am not allowed to do so

Comment: Then create a test program that exhibits the same symptom and show that. The exercise of creating the test program may help you solve the problem, and as it stands your question is asking us to speculate what's wrong with no information to support the guess.

Comment: I assume you know Derived::func() was actually called due to a log message.  Since gdb thinks you did not call that function at all, the easiest explanation would be maybe gdb is correct.

Comment: Yes I know via logging and the fact that when I have gdb print out the actual type of the object it is of the Derived type. And yes the function is virtual

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really enough detail in this question to answer it.  There could be many reasons for what you are seeing.  For example, the call from the derived function to the base function could have been turned into a tail call by the compiler, meaning that the derived call would not appear on the stack.